# If $g : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function which $\forall s\in S:g(s)\ge 0$ and $\exists s\in S:g(s)>0$, does $\int_{S}g>0$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to prove that if a continuous function $g : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ verifies that $\forall s \in S : g(s) \ge 0$ and $\exists s \in S :g(s) > 0$ where S is an open set that has volume $\Rightarrow\int_{S} g > 0$.

I think it might be useful to find a $B(s,r) \subset A $ which verifies $\forall k \in B(s,r): f(k) > 0$
but I'm not sure how I could do it.

I'm stuck on this proof, any hints or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{s': g(s') >\frac {g(s)} 2\}$ is an open set containing $s$ so there exists $r>0$ such that $B(s,r) \subset S$ and $g(s') > \frac {g(s)} 2$ for all $s' \in B(s,r) $.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use $\varepsilon := g(s)/2$ in the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity where $s \in S$ such that $g(s) > 0$.